# Remote Desktop only working one-way

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a laptop and a PC both running Windows 10. PC is connected to the router through wire and laptop through WiFi. The problem is that laptop's RDP can access my PC, but not the other way around (i.e. PC's RDP cannot connect to the laptop). I have ensured the following:

1. Both machines can ping each other.
2. Both machines can access each other's shared folders.
3. Remote Assistance is allowed on both machines.
4. RDP is in firewall's allowed list of programs on both machines.
5. Using IP instead of machine name also doesn't work.
6. There is no special error message in Event Viewer.

RDP spends some time saying "Initiating remote connection", but then fails with the following message:

> Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these
>   reasons:
>
> 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled.
>
> 2) The remote computer is turned off.
>
> 3) The remote computer is not available on the network
>
> Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the
>   network, and that remote access is enabled.

Obviously none of these 3 is the problem here. What else should I look for?

Comment: what version of Windows 10 is on the laptop?  Remote desktop is not enabled for the Home version

Comment: @Keltari: grrr... Is this documented somewhere? I have Win10 Home on the laptop and Win10 Pro on PC.

Comment: @Keltari: and do u mean "not enabled" or "not supported"? Means do I need to take some steps to enable it?

Comment: It is well documented, google it.  Even though the there is an "enable remote desktop" on home, it will not work.  Why MS has it there, is a mystery to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else banging their head against the wall, I found the a free library that works on Windows 10 Home. You can download it [here](https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap/releases/tag/v1.6). Follow these steps then **on Windows 10 Home machine**:

1. Unzip the downloaded file.
2. Run `install.bat`.
3. Run `RDPCheck.exe` to ensure that it is running fine. If u receive an error, run `update.bat` and then try `RDPCheck.exe` again.
4. If it runs successfully, simply run `RDPConf.exe` and now u can connect to this machine from other machines using the standard Remote Desktop Connection application.